# Oracle equivalent to Postgres' @> (contains) function

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I'm trying to write a conversion from PostgreSQL that will work in Oracle.
My problem is that I am struggling to find an Oracle SQL statement that will replace the Postgres `@>` (contains) operator.

The query in Postgres reads like this:

```
CASE    
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{Building}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL THEN 'Building Fill'
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"General Surface"}' AND descriptiveterm = '{"Multi Surface"}' THEN 'Multi Surface Fill'
```

etc., meaning that 'Building' or 'General Surface' (in the above example) should be contained within an array called descriptivegroup.

I've been trawling through Stackoverflow and other websites and I think the nearest equivalent I can find for `@>` in Oracle is 'member of' as in this example:

[How to check if an array contains a particular string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578316/how-to-check-if-an-array-contains-a-particular-string)

However, I'm struggling to work out how to work a statement like this into a CASE > WHEN type of statement so any help or suggestions that I could get from this community would be gratefully received!

Many thanks.

PS As promised, here is a truncated version of the Postgres query.  This isn't everything as it would be far too big:

```
CREATE TABLE osmm.topo_area_style AS SELECT
a.*,
CASE    
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{Building}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL THEN 'Building 

Fill'
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"General Surface"}' AND descriptiveterm = '{"Multi 

Surface"}' THEN 'Multi Surface Fill'
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"General Surface"}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL AND make 

= 'Natural' THEN 'Natural Fill'
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"Road Or Track"}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL AND make = 

'Manmade' THEN 'Road Or Track Fill'
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"General Surface"}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL AND make 

= 'Manmade' OR make = 'Unknown' THEN 'Manmade Fill'
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{Roadside}' AND make = 'Natural' THEN 'Roadside Natural 

Fill'
    ELSE 'Unclassified' 
    END AS style_description,
CASE
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{Building}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"General Surface"}' AND descriptiveterm = '{"Multi 

Surface"}' THEN 2
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"General Surface"}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL AND make 

= 'Natural' THEN 3
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"Road Or Track"}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL AND make = 

'Manmade' THEN 4
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{"General Surface"}' AND descriptiveterm IS NULL AND make 

= 'Manmade' OR make = 'Unknown' THEN 5
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{Roadside}' AND make = 'Natural' THEN 6
    WHEN descriptivegroup @> '{Roadside}' AND make = 'Manmade' OR descriptivegroup @> 

'{Roadside}' AND make = 'Unknown' THEN 7
    ELSE 99 
    END AS style_code
FROM osmm.topographicarea as a;
```

I don't have access to the table that this SQL was written for but as you can see the table being created is a straight copy of the existing table but this code adds another 2 columns which it then populates from the descriptivegroup and descriptiveterm.

Comment: How is descriptivegroup defined and populated? Is it a nested table, or is this in a PL/SQL block? Might be helpful to show more of the statement, sample data and expected result.

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement for the table in question. It also doesn't seem to be PostGIS related - the `@>` is a Postgres standard operator for e.g. arrays. I don't see any GIS specific stuff in your query.

Comment: Hi chaps, thanks for replying so quickly.  I will edit my original post if I can with some more details.

Comment: And what is the definition of `osmm.topographicarea`? Especially: what is the datatype of `descriptivegroup`?

Comment: [PostGIS does not have this operator](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Operators); it must be the [`@>` contains operator for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, the datatype for descriptivegroup is varchar; DDL below:
CREATE TABLE "DEV"."TOPOGRAPHICAREA" 
   ( "CALCULATEDAREAVALUE" NUMBER, 
 "CHANGEHISTORY" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
 "DESCRIPTIVEGROUP" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
 "DESCRIPTIVETERM" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
 "FEATURECODE" NUMBER, 
 "FID" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
 "GML_VERSION" NUMBER, 
 "MAKE" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE), 
 "PHYSICALLEVEL" NUMBER, 
 "PHYSICALPRESENCE" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE), 
 "GEOMETRY" "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY" , 
 "POLYGON_BROKEN" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
 "THEME" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
 "VERSIONDATE" DATE, 
 "MI_PRINX" NUMBER(38,0)

Comment: That is not the definition of that table in Postgres. As the `@>` is an array operator I'm pretty sure the column is defined as an **array** e.g. `text[]` or `varchar[]`. The closest thing in Oracle to a Postgres array would be a nested table - but that is horribly inconvenient to work with (compare to a Postgres array). Your question has nothing to do with PostGIS

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name.  My apologies, that was the table structure for the Oracle table.
In PostgreSQL the definitions for `descriptivegroup` and `descriptiveterm` would have been `varchar[]`.  For example, the data appears as comma separated text strings in the Oracle table as in DESCRIPTIVEGROUP
Tidal Water,General Surface,Road Or Track