# Expression is of wrong type -Oracle error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to check whether a value is a member of an array.
I tried following sample code from [How to check if an array contains a particular string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578316/how-to-check-if-an-array-contains-a-particular-string)

```
DECLARE
TYPE v_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
ais_array v_array ;

BEGIN
ais_array := ('Lb1','Lb2','Lb3','Lb613');
IF 'Lb1' member of ais_array THEN
   dbms_output.put_line('found');
END IF;
END;
/
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 16:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the constructor call for initialization, try the code bellow

```
declare
   type v_array is table of varchar2(200);
   ais_array v_array;

begin
   ais_array := v_array('Lb1', 'Lb2', 'Lb3', 'Lb613');
   if 'Lb1' member of ais_array then
      dbms_output.put_line('found');
   end if;
end;
```

I've added the `ais_array := v_array('Lb1', 'Lb2', 'Lb3', 'Lb613');`.